# Run unknown number of processes (for loop) and wait for them to finish in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have a bash script which does the following:

```
for server in $servers; do  # servers from input
     ssh $server <some long running command...>
done

# Rest of the code...
```

I would like to parallelize the `ssh` calls, but only continue to the rest of the code after all the servers have finished. I noticed similar questions here but all had either a fixed number of processes, or did not wait for finish. I would also accept an answer like `don't do it in bash!`. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ . It enables you to do things like like `parallel ssh {1} <some command> ::: $servers` and have everything run in parallel. You can specify number of jobs to run in parallel, logging and many other things. To see what will be run (without actually starting the jobs) try `parallel ssh {1} ::: $servers` for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
ssh $server <some long running command...>
```

by

```
ssh $server <some long running command...> &
```

and replace

```
done
```

by

```
done
wait
```

Comment: Wow, so simple? Will the wait work for all the processes?

Comment: Yes, if the process was started with `&`.
The prerequisite is that the ssh connections are established while the long running command is running on the remote server.

Comment: `wait` with no arguments waits for all background jobs in the current shell. `wait` with a single job specification waits for that one specific job. `wait -n` in newer versions of `bash` will wait for exactly one background job, and will exit as soon as any job completes.